# SharedPreferences nullPointerException when saving strings

Tags: java, android

I am working launcher for android. At the moment I am working for address book(yes I want to include it to my launcher), but I am getting `NullPointerException`.
Here is part of my main frame where class that causes error is called.

```
Numbers j = new Numbers();
                   EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number);
                   j.adNumber(text.getText().toString(), "1");
```

Here is the number class

```
public class Numbers extends Activity {
SharedPreferences pres;



public void adNumber(String number, String button){
    SharedPreferences  pres;

    pres = getSharedPreferences("1",0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pres.edit();
editor.putString(number,button);
editor.commit();
 }

  public String getNumber(String button){
  pres = getSharedPreferences("1",0);
  return pres.getString(button,"");
 }
}
```

and here is the error message:

```
06-29 12:51:39.476    8983-8983/oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher, PID: 8983
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:170)
        at oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher.Numbers.<init>(Numbers.java:26)
        at oo.seniorlauncher.com.o_seniorlauncher.MainFrame$1$1.onClick(MainFrame.java:46)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is Numbers an Activity in the first place?

Comment: Which is line 26 of the Numbers class? (`Numbers.java:26`)

Comment: its pres=getSharedPreferences("1",0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NPE is because Numbers is an Activity but doesn't have a valid context (or rather, it *isn't* one).

It looks like what you have done is made your Numbers class extend Activity so that you can call `getSharedPreferences` on it. However you can't just new an Activity in Android, you have to create it according to the [proper Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

If you want to be able to call `getSharedPreferences` inside your number class, you can get rid of `extends Activity`, add a `Context` member variable, and initialize it in the constructor.

```
public class Numbers
{
     Context mContext;
     public Numbers(Context context)
     {
         mContext = context;
     }
```

then you can call getSharedPreferences on it:

```
     pres = mContext.getSharedPreferences("1",0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare [ShardPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) object twice.
1. class level
2. in adNumber().

so, please remove one of that and declare like this with initiate.

```
SharedPreferences pres = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPres", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and used it anywhere is you declare it on class level.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `editor.putString(number,button);`, 'number' is your key and 'button' is your default value.

If you want to retrieve the value of 'number' in your SharedPreferences, you should call `getString(key, defValue)` as follow :

`return pres.getString(number, "");`

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

You have declared twice your SharedPreferences variable.

Also you need to call `getSharedPreference(String, int)` only once, if you need to access a specific shared variable you need only `pres.getString(label, default_value)`.